# UDP punch hole for a web-server?

Tags: node.js, sockets, curl, hole-punching

For my academic project, I am trying to achieve this.
A web server node JS application listening on port 3000. 
So If you `curl http://localhost:3000` you will get `Hello World!`. ( A simple web page.

Now I am running above webserver in my local machine. And my modem is behind NAT. Suppose If I port forward in the modem to `myip:3000` then it is open to the world. But here is the biggest thing I am stuck - I don't want to use the modem for port forwarding, instead, I will use third party server for UDP Punch Hole.

Now my requirement is anyone from net should able to access my webserver at `curl http://third-party-server-ip:3000`.

What I am trying is to write another client - which opens a connection to the third party server. Say it did a hole punching at port `41234`. That port is open. The third-party host can send something to that port.

Now anyone in the internet initiate this command `curl http://third-party-ip:3000` to the third party host. So the third party returns the **myip:udpPunchHolePort** i.e., `myip:41234`.

anyone will again curl to `myip:41234` it will be received by the node js UDP punch app, so it will redirect to `localhost:3000`. Finally, the `anyone` will receive the response from `localhost:3000`.

My two questions -

1. Is there any better way than the one I proposed here?
2. Is there any well-known node-js lib for this kind of stuff, I see,
   I can use  [UDP punch hole](https://www.npmjs.com/package/udp-hole-puncher). **Or** I am thinking to write a Lib to do this in general - does this sounds like re-inventing the wheel?

Note - 
In this academic project, we are trying to learn how to make any local application open to the world without port forwarding in the modem.

We read on [skype protocol analysis](http://377cloudsolutions.blogspot.com/2017/07/1-skype-protocol-analysis.html), that is also our inspiration.

[image: Flow of request]

Comment: It's unclear why you're trying to use UDP here.  You are trying to use the third party host as a proxy for your "behind the firewall" host.  There are a number of architectural ways to do that.  The most straightforward way I can think of would be for your "behind-the-firewall" server to open a connection to the third party proxy.  Because this connection is outbound, it will be allowed and because the connection is persistent, then both sides can send data over the connection.  Thus your third party proxy can send your "behind-the-firewall" server any data it wants at any time.

Comment: Though I don't know the specifics here, you can probably build this out of mostly pre-built components such as pre-built proxies and tunnels.

Comment: thanks @jfriend00 - I will try to understand "behind-the-firewall". Soon I will reply here if it works.

Comment: @jfriend00 - `... then both sides can send data over the connection`  Means `anyone` can reach to third party proxy to get the web page -  excellent idea. Just confirm me any example applications uses this strategy, say UDP punch hole technique used in skype(maybe), similarly any well-known application uses this kind of strategy?

Comment: All browser pages that use socket.io or webSockets are getting this same benefit.  Client behind a firewall connects to a server, thus allowing the  server to send data to them at any time even though they are located behind a firewall.  Most chat clients use something like this.

Comment: perhaps you should distinguish TCP and UDP in your diagram.

Comment: Hello @Sam you are really re-inventing wheels for sure. You just need nginx proxy server in between. we are doing that in our current project. Everytime each & every request you send, it  will go to nginx proxy server & then request will be send by nginx to your application http://localhost:3000. Here is detailed manual for nginx https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Comment: @InderRSingh NGINX running on the third party machine, wont be able to traverse the NAT to the local machine.
@Sam It seems to me that this problem can be easily solved with an SSH reverse tunnel. `ssh -R 80:localhost:3000 user@thirdpartyip` assuming sshd on the third party has the `GatewayPorts yes` setting enabled.

Comment: @InderRSingh - looks very promising for further investigation on it. thank you. I will dig deeper into it. :)

Comment: @Magnus - Thank you - I will look into reverse tunnel also.

Comment: @Magnus - reverse tunnel looks very simple way :) lemme try it

Comment: @Sam SSH tunnelling won't help. It requires the firewall to be running an SSH server, which is essentially never available. The (extremely rare, typically homemade) firewalls that do have an SSH server will almost always have port forwarding and/or UPnP available as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that won't work.

1. HTTP runs over TCP, not UDP. Punching a UDP hole doesn't do you any good -- any TCP connection to the backend HTTP server will still fail.
2. HTTP redirects are not magic. If a user cannot access a specific host:port, redirecting them to a URL on that host:port will just make their browser time out when it requests that URL.
3. You cannot send a response from a different host:port from what the browser requested, because there is no TCP connection established with that endpoint.

Comment: what if I punch TCP hole instead of udp?  I see tcp hole is possible, just wanted to know your opinion on that.

Comment: @Sam Some theoretical techniques for TCP hole punching exist, but they aren't reliable -- they depend on implementation details of the firewall. My advice? Pick another project. What you're trying to accomplish here is not possible.

Comment: thank you so much :) I am just waiting a few more days to accept this answer before I completely discard this project.

Comment: 4) You cannot udp punch a hole and expect it to be open for others. Each of your visitors would need to open a hole himself.

Comment: Look into Universal Plug and Play

Comment: what about HTTP3, over UDP?